# How to make a visualization, for example a column chart, using only SQL?

Tags: sql, data-visualization, presto

I need to make a visualization using only SQL. I would like to make both a column chart and a histogram

Answer (score 0):

How about using bar function?

```
presto:default> select * from test order by 1;
 name | value
------+-------
 a    |    10
 b    |    20
 c    |     5
 d    |    15
 e    |    25

presto:default> select name, bar(value, value) from test order by 1;
```

[image]
https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/color.html#bar